# NoMethodError in EventRegistrationsController#new undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a website for a sports coach. I am currently trying to make a form that lets users of my website sign up to different sporting events. When a user is signed in I want them to be able to click a register button beside a particular event and then their `user_id` and `event_id` will be put into the table that I have created. Here is the new section of registrations controller:

```
    def new
       @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
       @user = User.current
       @user_id = @user.id

       @event_registration = @event.event_registrations.build({:user_id => @user_id},
      :without_protection =>true)
     end
```

So basically this is finding the relevant id's. The event id is fine but when it gets to the current user it doesn't seem to find the id of the person that is signed in. I have a sessions helper which is:

```
    module SessionsHelper
      def sign_in(user)
        remember_token = User.new_remember_token
        user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
        self.current_user = user
      end

     def signed_in?
       !current_user.nil?
     end

     def current_user=(user)
       @current_user = user
     end

     def current_user
       remember_token = User.hash(cookies[:remember_token])
       @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
     end

     def current_user?(user)
       user == current_user
     end

     def signed_in_user
       unless current_user
       store_location
       redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
     end
    end
```

I think I have included all the relevant parts of the code here. Would anyone know why it is not finding the current users id?

Comment: you are using `current` while the method name is `current_user` and i  don't think you should call it as `User.current_user` but not sure either the correct way? since seesionmodule is not clear to me

Comment: yea I tried that but it then says **undefined method `current_user' for #** @Nimir

Comment: in your `RegistrationsController` `include SessionHelper` and change `@user = User.current` to `current_user`

Comment: This doesn't seem to have changed the error. I'm guessing I need to go back and make sure the sessions helper is actually being used. A user can sign in and access signed in pages so I kind of figured the sessions helper was being used correctly @bjhaid

Comment: Oh wait I think I misread what you said. I already have include SessionHelper in the application controller, I changed `@user = User.current` to `@user = current_user` and it worked. Thanks for the help guys, really appreciate it @bjhaid @Nimir

Comment: @user3494239 I would add it as an answer and you can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `RegistrationsController` include the `SessionHelper` as below:

`include SessionHelper`

and change

`@user = User.current`

to:

`@user = current_user`